# Issue with Sort native method Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm trying to order elements using native `sort` method.

**Code:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
Collections.sort(list);
```

**Input 1:**

```
Before order: 65 31 37 37 72 76 61 35 57 37
After order:  31 35 37 37 37 57 61 65 72 76
Expected:     Ok.
```

**Input 2:**

```
Before order: 45 186 185 55 51 51 22 78 64 26 49 21
After order:  185 186 21 22 26 45 49 51 51 55 64 78
Expected:     21 22 26 45 49 51 51 55 64 78 185 186
```

The problem is that the method is sorting wrong in some cases, how can I solve it?

Comment: use a `Comparator`

Comment: Can you tell us your expected result and the actual result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `List<String>`, so `Collections.sort` is ordering the `String`(s) lexicographically. You could use a `List<Integer>` like

```
List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList(45, 186, 185, 55, 51, 51, 22, 78, 64, 26, 49, 21);
Collections.sort(al);
System.out.println(al);
```

But, if you must use `String`(s) then you'll need to provide a custom `Comparator` (because the default `String` ordering isn't what you want). Something like,

```
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("45", "186", "185", "55", "51", "51", //
        "22", "78", "64", "26", "49", "21");
Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1), Integer.parseInt(o2));
    }
});
System.out.println(al);
```

which outputs (like the first example)

```
[21, 22, 26, 45, 49, 51, 51, 55, 64, 78, 185, 186]
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that in Java 8 you can do it particularly succinctly: `list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));`

Comment: Thanks. And, yes I have to use it as String. Nice contribution @PaulBoddington. By the way, when I wrote that code of @ElliottFricsh, Netbeans shows me another option to use lambda: `(String o1, String o2) -> Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1), Integer.parseInt(o2)));`. Just to contribute also.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Integer comparator.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
Collections.sort(list);
```

or

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"45", "186", "185", "55", "51", "51", "22", "78", "64", "26", "49", "21"});
Comparator<String> cmp = (String o1, String o2) -> Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
Collections.sort(list,cmp);
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort by

1. integer value of string

That is

```
Collections.sort(list,
    Comparator.comparing(Integer::parseInt));
```

Or sort by

1. length of string
2. string itself

That is

```
Collections.sort(list,
    Comparator.comparing(String::length)
              .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```